# Can we export data extension records daily and upload on a 3rd party SFTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, files, ftp

Can we export data extension records daily and upload on a 3rd party SFTP?

I understand that file can be uploaded to marketing cloud FTP BUT in this case, file needs to be provided to 3rd party and we do not want them to access marketing cloud FTP.

*Do not have the option to work with API so my question is related to what we can do within the marketing cloud system / user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a file to any FTP. You just need to setup the FTP details in the Administration area.

Under Administration > Data Management > File Locations you can create a new FTP location. Under Location Type select External FTP Site.

You will then have the option to select this location as part of your file export activity in Automation Studio.

[image: sfmc file location]

This works the same for SFTP as well.

Comment: Found it - Thank you @travis-naughton